# countpattern: invalid 'nrow' value (too large or NA)

Tags: r, e1071

I'm having difficulty applying the countpattern function from e1071 package. I aim to find binary patterns and count them. My data consists of a large matrix (1117200 elements, 9.6 MB) with 114 columns and 9800 rows. When applied the function, I keep receiving the following error message:

> Error in matrix(0, 2^nvar, nvar) :
> invalid 'nrow' value (too large or NA)

I was testing the function increasing gradually the number of columns from my data, and it worked until use ~19 columns (just a small part of my 114 columns in total). More than that, it produced an Error.

So, the solution might be to find a more efficient function/algorithm than this function to find the binary patterns. However, before moving on, I wanted to ask if there is a way to contour this situation using the countpattern function?

Thanks for your time!

As requested by @slamballais, a data samples is presented as following,

`data_sample <- rbind(c(1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0), c(1,0,0,1,1,1,9,1,0,0,1), c(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0), c(0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1), c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0))`

Comment: Do you need to know every possible binary combination? That's 2^114 which is 2.10^34! Given that you only have 9800 rows, you have in your data up to 9800 binary combinations. There are more efficient way to do summarize them. Here is the [code of the countpattern function](https://github.com/cran/e1071/blob/master/R/countpattern.R), where you can see it starts out by creating a matrix with a size for all possible combinations, which causes the error.

Comment: Can you give a sample of your dataset (or create a dataset that looks similar)? Because I'm pretty sure this can be done more easily, depending on your requirements.

Comment: @slamballais I already added a small portion of my dataset. Just 5 rows and 11 columns. My goal is to find every possible binary combination considering 9800 rows and 114 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does

```r
table(apply(data_sample,1, paste,collapse=""))
```

work?

Comment: It worked perfectly: fast and accurate to my full dataset. Many thanks!